# How to make sure a google spreadsheet is properly uptadeted by a GAS (copy range) function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to copy a range of cells from one place to another with this line of code:

`cell.offset(1, 0, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(cell.offset(nextRow, 0));`

The range to be copied is always the same; the only thing is changing is `nextRow`, that is the row to copy to.

The original range has cells with values and formulas.

Everything seems fine, but, for an unknown reason, the copy procedure is behaving erratically:

- one time, everything works as expected;
- another time, it doesn't copy one of the cells;
- another time, it doesn't copy the formulas, only the values;
- another time, it mixes the inconsistences above.

Copying from the UI is fine.

The fact that I had the spreadsheet open as I run the function has something to do with it?

The big question: **is there a way to ensure the range is properly copied?**

UPDATE:

More code to try to make it clearer:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ScriptProperties.getProperty('SpreadSheetId'));
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Matches");
var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var cell = sheet.getRange('a1');
cell.offset(1, 0, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(cell.offset(nextRow, 0));
```

Comment: *The fact that I had the spreadsheet open as I run the function has something to do with it?*

As you`` say , this can indeed be relevant, could you show how you define cell and sheet?  Are you using get activeSpreadSheet?

Comment: @Sergeinsas I updated the question to show the relevant part of the code. The problem occurring it's not that it doesn't copy at all. It did copy all the times, sometimes as expected and other times missing/messing some of the data.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I guess now the question is perfectly clear ;-)

Comment: Maybe it is better just refactor my code and use `.setFormulas` / `.setValues` instead. This would increase complexity ... well, just thinking. Maybe later I'll do some tests.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've got something acceptable.
The code below didn't throw any error so far, and I'm sticking with it till something better comes up.
Thank you guys, anyway.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ScriptProperties.getProperty('SpreadSheetId'));
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Matches");
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
var cell = sheet.getRange('a1');
var formulasToCheck = [1,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]; //cells 2 to 16 are being set in another place
var formulasOk = true;
var loopCount = 0;
do {
    formulasOk = true;
    cell.offset(1, 0, 1, lastCol).copyTo(cell.offset(lastRow, 0));
    var formulas = cell.offset(lastRow, 0, 1, lastCol).getFormulas()[0];
    loopCount++;
    for (var i = 0; i < formulasToCheck.length; i++) {
        if (formulas[formulasToCheck[i]].slice(0,1) != "=") {
            formulasOk = false;
            break;
        }
    }
} while (!formulasOk && loopCount<5);
```

Maybe a `flush()` would suffice. But, this way, I'm very sure the values/formulas are being set properly.

Answer (score -1):

I would test with something simple, for example hard code your cell locations. 
I have used the function many times, and it works every time for me.

Also... did not test it, but this looks wrong : cell.offset(**lastRow**, 0)

Comment: `cell.offset` is being used as it should be: with an offset of 'n' rows represented by 'lastRow'. And, most of the time, it gives the expected results.

Comment: You are suggesting copyTo has an intermittent bug. Would be good to know if it has or not.

Comment: I was not going this way, but, yes, it seems so. But, if it happens only with my code/spreadsheet, it could be my fault. I'm not with enough time right now to do extensive testing but, I'll keep updating this question as much as possible to narrow down the possibilities.